# ROS msg cannot locate message

Tags: rosmsg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am learning the tutorial for ROS. I ran into this error when I try the code below. I used nano editor to edit the package.xml and CMakeLists.txt as directed in the tutorial.

```
ubuntu@arm:~/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials$ rosmsg show beginner_tutorials/Num
Unable to load msg [beginner_tutorials/Num]: Cannot locate message [Num]: unknown package [beginner_tutorials] on search path [{'rosconsole': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rosconsole/msg'], 'catkin': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/msg'], 'angles': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/angles/msg'], 'rosgraph': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rosgraph/msg'], 'rqt_py_console': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_py_console/msg'], 'nodelet_topic_tools': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/nodelet_topic_tools/msg'], 'rqt_graph': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_graph/msg'], 'nodelet_tutorial_math': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/nodelet_tutorial_math/msg'], 'qt_gui': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/qt_gui/msg'], 'smclib': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/smclib/msg'], 'roslib': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/roslib/msg'], 'roscpp_serialization': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/roscpp_serialization/msg'], 'rosbuild': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rosbuild/msg'], 'qt_gui_cpp': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/qt_gui_cpp/msg'], 'rqt_publisher': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_publisher/msg'], 'roswtf': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/roswtf/msg'], 'genlisp': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/genlisp/msg'], 'shape_msgs': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/shape_msgs/msg'], 'rqt_topic': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_topic/msg'], 'rqt_action': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_action/msg'], 'rqt_top': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_top/msg'], 'diagnostic_msgs': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/diagnostic_msgs/msg'], 'rosgraph_msgs': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rosgraph_msgs/msg'], 'rosboost_cfg': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rosboost_cfg/msg'], 'genmsg': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/genmsg/msg'], 'pluginlib': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/pluginlib/msg'], 'rqt_msg': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_msg/msg'], 'rqt_service_caller': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_service_caller/msg'], 'xmlrpcpp': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/xmlrpcpp/msg'], 'rosmaster': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rosmaster/msg'], 'rosnode': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rosnode/msg'], 'bond': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/bond/msg'], 'rospack': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rospack/msg'], 'actionlib_msgs': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/actionlib_msgs/msg'], 'rqt_image_view': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_image_view/msg'], 'rqt_console': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_console/msg'], 'python_qt_binding': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/python_qt_binding/msg'], 'gencpp': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/gencpp/msg'], 'rqt_gui_cpp': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_gui_cpp/msg'], 'rqt_bag': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_bag/msg'], 'rqt_gui': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_gui/msg'], 'qt_gui_py_common': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/qt_gui_py_common/msg'], 'roscpp_traits': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/roscpp_traits/msg'], 'rosout': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rosout/msg'], 'rostopic': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rostopic/msg'], 'visualization_msgs': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/visualization_msgs/msg'], 'message_generation': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/message_generation/msg'], 'rostime': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rostime/msg'], 'rosservice': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rosservice/msg'], 'actionlib_tutorials': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/actionlib_tutorials/msg'], 'rosunit': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rosunit/msg'], 'roscpp_tutorials': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/roscpp_tutorials/msg'], 'turtle_actionlib': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/turtle_actionlib/msg'], 'bondcpp': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/bondcpp/msg'], 'rosconsole_bridge': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rosconsole_bridge/msg'], 'pluginlib_tutorials': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/pluginlib_tutorials/msg'], 'roslz4': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/roslz4/msg'], 'rqt_dep': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_dep/msg'], 'rosmsg': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rosmsg/msg'], 'rospy': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rospy/msg'], 'turtlesim': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlesim/msg'], 'rosparam': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rosparam/msg'], 'stereo_msgs': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/stereo_msgs/msg'], 'trajectory_msgs': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/trajectory_msgs/msg'], 'rosbash': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rosbash/msg'], 'rqt_reconfigure': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_reconfigure/msg'], 'rqt_bag_plugins': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_bag_plugins/msg'], 'rqt_plot': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_plot/msg'], 'topic_tools': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/topic_tools/msg'], 'rostest': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rostest/msg'], 'cpp_common': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/cpp_common/msg'], 'nodelet': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/nodelet/msg'], 'dynamic_reconfigure': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/dynamic_reconfigure/msg'], 'genpy': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/genpy/msg'], 'rqt_shell': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_shell/msg'], 'std_msgs': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/std_msgs/msg'], 'roscreate': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/roscreate/msg'], 'image_transport': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/image_transport/msg'], 'rqt_launch': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_launch/msg'], 'qt_dotgraph': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/qt_dotgraph/msg'], 'cv_bridge': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/cv_bridge/msg'], 'rosbag_storage': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rosbag_storage/msg'], 'roslang': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/roslang/msg'], 'std_srvs': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/std_srvs/msg'], 'mk': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/mk/msg'], 'message_runtime': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/message_runtime/msg'], 'bondpy': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/bondpy/msg'], 'rqt_web': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_web/msg'], 'class_loader': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/class_loader/msg'], 'cmake_modules': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/cmake_modules/msg'], 'nav_msgs': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/nav_msgs/msg'], 'rosmake': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rosmake/msg'], 'rqt_srv': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_srv/msg'], 'roscpp': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/roscpp/msg'], 'actionlib': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/actionlib/msg'], 'rosclean': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rosclean/msg'], 'roslisp': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/roslisp/msg'], 'message_filters': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/message_filters/msg'], 'sensor_msgs': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/sensor_msgs/msg'], 'rospy_tutorials': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rospy_tutorials/msg'], 'rqt_gui_py': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_gui_py/msg'], 'rqt_py_common': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_py_common/msg'], 'roslaunch': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/roslaunch/msg'], 'rqt_logger_level': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_logger_level/msg'], 'geometry_msgs': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/geometry_msgs/msg'], 'rosbag': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rosbag/msg'], 'rosbag_migration_rule': ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rosbag_migration_rule/msg']}]
```

Kindly assist me to fix the error. I need to progress in my project as soon as possible. Thanks for the help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197057/ros-msg-cannot-locate-message/) by [Glory](https://answers.ros.org/users/19749/glory/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2014-11-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have fixed the error by sourcing the environment : $ source devel/setup.bash

---

Originally posted by [Glory](https://answers.ros.org/users/19749/glory/) with karma: 76 on 2014-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Science](https://answers.ros.org/users/20763/science/) on 2014-11-13**:
Thank you very much

**Comment by [thepirate16](https://answers.ros.org/users/26128/thepirate16/) on 2016-03-01**:
I think not only that, you also have to catkin_make from the catkin_ws, as sourcing alone didn't work for me :)

i mean:

catkin_ws$ catkin_make

catkin_ws$ source devel/setup.bash

**Comment by [PabloGN](https://answers.ros.org/users/25081/pablogn/) on 2016-03-21**:
Thank you!
It is a easy but tricky error, I have been around this error for some time when declaring a custom message.

**Comment by [Kansai](https://answers.ros.org/users/54052/kansai/) on 2021-04-01**:
it is not an easy error. I source the environment but it persists. Furthermore even though the message is not loaded, it still works (topics with this message are published)